# SQL to LINQ query asp.net

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am currently trying to get some statistics for my website but i cant seem to create the query for my database to get the username that if found most frequent in all the rows.

The sql query should look something like this:

```
SELECT username FROM Views GROUP BY 'username' ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1
```

How do i make that query in my controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var username = db.Views.GroupBy(v => v.username).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()).First().Key
```

Comment: Thanks for the great help! The first answer already seems to work very good!

Answer (score 1):

```
(from a in Views
group a by a.username into b
let c = b.count()
orderby c descending
select a.username).take(1);
```

Your query conversion .....

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do that query using LINQ:

```
var temp = (from a in Views
            group a.username by a.username into b
            orderby b.Count() descending
            select b.Key).Take(1);
```

Comment: OrderByDescending() is one keyword

Comment: @esastincy: There is no `orderbydescending` in the "SQL-like" syntax, you have to write it as `orderby alias.fieldname descending`.

Comment: Thanks for the responds aswell m8!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do LIMIT 1 (mysql), since LinqToSql only generates TSql from MSSqlServer.